# In jquery mobile how to prevent to add some specific classes to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html, jquery-mobile

For example in this case

[image]

I just don't want the class `ui-shadow` in the element and without overriding the css.

I tried `data-shadow="false"` but it doesn't hide the shadow. is there any other attribute to do this?

Comment: Ugly solution would be .removeClass("ui-shadow").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure you can remove just one class the jQM adds without the use of jQuery or rolling your own theme.

For native elements you have the option to set the attribute like this:

```
 data-role="none"
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

You could roll your own theme with the new jQM Theme Roller:

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Or (Not sure if this is the best solution as it will probably break something) remove the CSS for `ui-shadow` but I wouldn't opt for this.

Last use jQuery and remove the class

```
$('$element_id').removeClass('ui-shadow');

// this might need a refresh as well
$('#page_id').trigger('create');
```

Since I see it's a list you could refresh like this as well

```
 $('ul').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: While I don't know of another method of removing specific classes other than using javascript, I can confirm that `data-role='none'` will prevent jQM from adding _any_ classes.

Comment: @Aaron not _any_ classes. an element like `<a href="#" data-role="none">` used inside `<div data-role="header">` will still get `class="ui-btn-left"` (for whatever reason - using jqm 1.4.1)

Answer (score 2):

You must apply the `data-shadow="false"` to the modal container (the element which has the `data-role="popup"` attribute).

Example:

```
<a href="#modal-foo" data-rel="popup">Trigger</a>

<div id="modal-foo" data-role="popup" data-shadow="false">
  Crazy modal stuff!
</div>
```